# How to upload a large file in Azure blob storage from angular app directly

Tags: angular, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have the connection string and container name of azure storage. I want to upload a large file from my angular app to azure storage directly. I also want to show the uploading progress. How can I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/stottle-uk/stottle-angular-blob-storage-upload/tree/master/src/app/azure-storage

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding this code

Comment: @tomalhossain Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to upload file to Azure blob, please refer to the following steps

1. Create an angular web app

```
ng new <appname>
```

2. install Azure storage SDk

```
npm install @azure/storage-blob
```

2. Update app.component.html File

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="file">Choose File</label>
  <input type="file"
         id="file"
         (change)="onFileChange($event)">
</div>
```

4. Update Environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  accountName : "<account name>",
  containerName:"",
   key:""
};
```

5. Add the following code in polyfills.ts

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = require( 'process' );
(window as any).Buffer = require( 'buffer' ).Buffer;
```

6. Add the following code in app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {BlobServiceClient,AnonymousCredential,newPipeline } from '@azure/storage-blob';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'web1';
  currentFile : File =null;
  onFileChange(event) {
    this.currentFile = event.target.files[0];
    this.upload();
 }

 async upload(){
// generate account sas token
  const accountName =environment.accountName;
  const key=environment.key;
  const start = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (15 * 60 * 1000));
  const end = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
const signedpermissions = 'rwdlac';
  const signedservice = 'b';
  const signedresourcetype = 'sco';
  const signedexpiry = end.toISOString().substring(0, end.toISOString().lastIndexOf('.')) + 'Z';
  const signedProtocol = 'https';
  const signedversion = '2018-03-28';

  const StringToSign =
      accountName+ '\n' +
      signedpermissions + '\n' +
      signedservice + '\n' +
      signedresourcetype + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedexpiry + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedProtocol + '\n' +
signedversion + '\n';
  const crypto =require('crypto')
   const sig = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'base64')).update(StringToSign, 'utf8').digest('base64');
  const sasToken =`sv=${(signedversion)}&ss=${(signedservice)}&srt=${(signedresourcetype)}&sp=${(signedpermissions)}&se=${encodeURIComponent(signedexpiry)}&spr=${(signedProtocol)}&sig=${encodeURIComponent(sig)}`;
  const containerName=environment.containerName;

            const pipeline =newPipeline (new AnonymousCredential(),{
            retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 }, // Retry options
            userAgentOptions: { userAgentPrefix: "AdvancedSample V1.0.0" }, // Customized telemetry string
            keepAliveOptions: {
                // Keep alive is enabled by default, disable keep alive by setting false
                enable: false
            }
            });

            const blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`,
                                                             pipeline  )
            const containerClient =blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
            if(!containerClient.exists()){
            console.log("the container does not exit")
            await containerClient.create()

            }
            const client = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(this.currentFile.name)
           const response = await client.uploadBrowserData(this.currentFile,{
                  blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
                  concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
                  onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev),
                  blobHTTPHeaders :{blobContentType:this.currentFile.type}
                  })
    console.log(response._response.status)
 }
}
```

7 Test. I upload a 1.3 GB [video](https://blobstorage0516.blob.core.windows.net/test1/test.mp4).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am getting CORS error with this solution. I have configured azure storage to accept requests from all origins. any idea @Jim Xu

Comment: Allow put and post kind of request too, and Cross error shud go away.